# How can I refresh a page via jQuery and ensure that there's a connection?

Tags: jquery, refresh

I toyed around with .load() and .ajax(), but i didn't get to an end. Here's what I need:
Everey minute the function shall check if it can load a certain page. 
if the connection succeeds, I want the page to be refreshed, if not, nothing shall happen, the script shall retry later.

I'm using the jQueryTimers plugin. this is my code so far:

```
//reload trigger
$(document).everyTime('60s', 'pagerefresh', reloadPage, 0, true);

//refresh function
function reloadPage() {
    $.ajax({
        url:'index-1.php',
        type:'HEAD',
        success: location.reload(true)
        })
}
```

I have no idea how to tell jQ what I want. any hint appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By writing `success: location.reload()`, you are calling `reload` immediately, and setting the `success` parameter to the whatever `reload` returns (which is `undefined`)

You need to use a anonymous function that calls `reload` as the `success` callback, like this:

```
    success: function() { location.reload(true); }
```

Comment: thanks for your help! that helped me out, the page immediately gets loaded when I reconnect to the net.

Comment: done. I want to follow up on my question, so I posted myself an answer. or how can I refine my question here on stackoverflow?

Answer (score 0):

thanks to SLaks, jQuery retries to reload now.

however, if I pull the internet cable off the PC, it still clears the screen and doesnt trigger the error. here's my new attempt:

```
$.ajax({
        url:'index.php',
        type:'HEAD',
        success: function() { location.reload(true); },
        error: function() {$('DIV').append('<p>ERROR</p>');}
        })
```

Comment: Add a random number to the URL to avoid caching (`url: 'index.php' + Math.random()`)

Comment: Also, install [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com), replace `location.reload` with `console.log(arguments)`, and check what happens on the Console tab as you unplug the connection.

Comment: cool, thanks, I like the approach.. BTW: I use opera dragonfly;)